# Script to take username and password

Tags: shell-script

I need to stop few services. whenever we entred the command to stop the service it'll prompt for username and password. We need to automate this whole scenario to take username and password directly from script or from file.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080324/how-to-pass-password-to-a-command-in-bash could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Does the command accept username and password via stdin? If yes:

```
printf "%s\n" "$username" "$password" | your_command
```